# LibreOffice: Keyboard shortcut to apply latest style

Tags: libreoffice-writer

Can I assign a keyboard shortcut that will apply the same styles as I just applied a different place?

**Background**

I have a text with mixed character styles. It will be easy for me to simply write the text and then mark each word that should have the style applied and then press a shortcut.

Comment: This would be helpful to me too. I often have to apply the "Source text" style, for example, to certain words and phrases. But there's no quick way to do it.